# How to access nested JSON graphql object passed into react child component, then list those items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

**GraphQL:**

```
{
 "data": [ 
   "theProducts": { 
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Fitness bands",
    "resistanceLevels": {
         "UltraHeavy": 10,
         "Heavy": 8,
         "Medium": 6 },
    "prices": [
         16.8,
         24.9
         13.2   
           ]
      }  
   ] 
}
```

I am trying to get the `resistanceBands` JSON object and the `price` array to map to the react child component (the query is defined in the parent component) and render the items in a list with bullet points.

**Parent Component:**

```
const GET_PRODUCT_DATA = gql`
  query getProducts {
    theProducts {
      id
      name
      resistanceLevels
      prices   
    }
  }

`
// How I am mapping data (name, etc) into the child component

const productsToRender = data.theProducts 
 {productsToRender.map( product => <ProductDisplay key={product.id} product={ product } />) } 

// How can map the object and array to display their items to the ProductDisplay child component?
```

**Child Component:**

```
<div>
 <h1>{product.name}</h1> // This works
  <p>Resistance Levels | Intensity:</p>
 <ul>
  <li>{product.resistanceLevels}</li> // This doesnt
 </ul>

 <p>Prices</p>
  <ul>
  <li>{product.prices}</li> // This doesnt
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.map()` for `prices` also because that's an array as:

```
<ul>
  {product.prices.map(p => <li>{p}</li>)}
</ul>
```

Also for `resistanceLevels` you can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combination as:

```js
const resistanceLevels = {
   "UltraHeavy": 10,
   "Heavy": 8,
   "Medium": 6
};

const result = Object.keys(resistanceLevels)
                     .map(k => resistanceLevels[k]);

console.log(result);
```

Read from the documentation:

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names, iterated in the same order that a normal loop would.

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

I guess this gives you the idea how to move further based on the example of `prices.map()`.

Comment: Thank you for breaking this down perfectly! Quick question about the passing the object.keys() to the child component! 

My attempt: 

    `<ul>{result.map(([key, value]) => {return (<li>{key} : {value}</li>);})}</ul>`

However, I am getting a Reference error stating "resistanceLevels"  is not defined?

Added: `const result = Object.keys(resistanceLevels).map(k => resistanceLevels[k]);`

Comment: My guess is that this may be because I defined `result` in the child component, whereas the parent component is where the query is defined? If I need to define result in the parent component how can I pass the result element to the child and render the key, values?

Comment: Have you tried as `Object.keys(product.resistanceLevels)` in the child component? That property lives in `product` object based on your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
const ParentComponent =()=>{
   return(
      <div>
       {productsToRender.map(product => <ProductDisplay key={product.id} product={product }/>) }
      </div>
   )

}
export default ParentComponent;


const ProductDisplay =(props)=>{
   return (
      <div>
         <h1>{product.name}</h1> 
         <p>Resistance Levels | Intensity:</p>
         <ul>
            {Object.entries(props.product.resistanceLevels).map(([key, value]) =>{
                return(
                    <li>{key} : {value}</li>
                )
            })}
           </ul>
           <ul>
               {
                   props.product.prices.map(item => {
                       <li>{item}</li>
               })
               }
           </ul>
     </div>
   )
}
```